# Populate drop-down in jsp page with data from MySQL in Java Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp, dropdown

I need to get the name of the below table in a drop-down list in jsp with its value as the primary-key from the table.

In the jsp page there is nothing showing in the drop-down list.

@Autowired
GenderService genderService;

```
@Autowired
SalutationService salutationService;

@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView showSave()
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("save");
    List<GenderMST> genderList = genderService.getAllGenderMST();
    mav.addObject("genderList", genderList);
    mav.addObject("save-sal", new SalutationMST());
    return mav;
}

@GetMapping("/search")
public ModelAndView showAll()
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("search");
    List<SalutationMST> salutationList = salutationService.getAllSalutationMST();
    mav.addObject("salutationList", salutationList);
    return mav;
}

@PostMapping("/saveSalutation")
public ModelAndView createSalutation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("save-sal") SalutationMST salutationMST) 
{
    salutationService.saveOrUpdateSalutationMST(salutationMST);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/save");

}



@GetMapping("/updateSal/{id}")
public ModelAndView editSalutation(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) 
{
    SalutationMST salutationMST = salutationService.getSalutationMSTBySalutationID(id);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("save");
    List<GenderMST> genderList = genderService.getAllGenderMST();
    mav.addObject("genderList", genderList);
    mav.addObject("save-sal", salutationMST);
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: While debugging do you see any item in `listGender` in your Controller? Where do you have your JSPs? Do you have `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view. suffix` configured?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Very helpful. The problem was I didn't call that.